# ARCore Android: unable to find the child nodes for a parent object?

Tags: android, opengl-es, arcore

I was working on ArCore in android; I was looking for these nodes with names inside my 3d model.

I tried creating a function and search for a specific name but when I checked it in android studio the only name which i get is "Node" and nothing else.

```
val childNode = getChildNodeByName(transformableNode, "TEXT_BOUNDING_BOX")

private fun getChildNodeByName(
        parentNode: TransformableNode,
        targetName: String,
    ): TransformableNode? {
        for (childNode in parentNode.children) {
            Log.d("3DTag", "Child Node Name: ${childNode.name}")
            if (childNode.name == targetName) {
                return childNode as TransformableNode
            }
        }
        return null
    }
```

I tried checking tranformableNode.scene.children but still the names inside that I found to be "Node" and nothing else which I can see in blender. How to get these child?

[image]